# Is matrix similarity transitive?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What is the difference between a similar matrix and a diagonal matrix? According to my textbook, the definition for both is basically: $B=P^{-1}AP$.

Say if there are three matrices: $A$, $B$ and $C$. If $A$ is similar to $B$, and $B$ is similar to $C$, does this mean that $A$ is similar to $C$?

Comment: There's no such thing as a similar matrix. Two matrices can be similar. A diagonal matrix is a square matrix in which all the entries outside of the main diagonal are zero.

Comment: And two (square) matrices $A,B$ are similar if and only if there exists $P$ so that $B=P^{-1}AP$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make my question clear. I meant if two matrices A and B are similar, does this mean one of the matrices is a diagonal matrix? Since the definition says that if B=(P^-1)AP, then B is similar to A, and also that B is a diagonal matrix? Thank you very much.

Comment: @mmath Can you state the definition verbatim from the book, please? The answer to the first question in your last comment is trivially no. For instance $A=IAI^{-1}$, this means $A$ is similar to itself. So if you pick a non-diagonal $A$, you get two matrices (which happen to be only one) which are similar and none is diagonal.

Comment: @GitGud Definition: If A and B are square matrices, then we say that B is similar to A if there is an invertible matrix P such that B = P$^{-1}$AP. A is said to be diagonalizable if it is similar to some diagonal matrix such that D = P$^{-1}$AP.

Comment: @mmath OK, everything is fine with that, (though not very well written). Can you please tell me again what you want to ask? I can't really tell what you're missing.

Comment: @GitGud My question was if two matrices are similar, then does it mean one of them is a diagonal matrix. You already solved my problem in the previous comments, so I'm all good now. Thanks :)

Comment: @mmath If that is all regarding this question, I suggest you answer your own question below, so this question doesn't come up as unanswered. alternatively you can delete the question, but that that's usually frowned upon here.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is similar to $B$ and $B$ is similar to $C$, then yes, $A$ is in fact similar to $C$.

**Proof** By definition, $A$ is similar to $B$ means that there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $$B = PAP^{-1}.$$ Similarly (pun not intended), there exists an invertible matrix $Q$ such that $C = QBQ^{-1}$ and therefore $B = Q^{-1}CQ.$ Replace $B$ in the first equation and you get
$$ Q^{-1}CQ = PAP^{-1} $$
$$ QQ^{-1}CQ = QPAP^{-1} $$
$$ CQQ^{-1}= QPAP^{-1}Q^{-1}$$
$$ C = QPAP^{-1}Q^{-1} = QPA(QP)^{-1} $$
Thus, we can see clearly that there exists an invertible matrix $QP$ that makes $A$ similar to $C$ and the proof is done.

Answer (score 1):

Similarity is a special case of equivalence. Equivalence is defined as:

$A \sim B$ if there are invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $PAQ=B$. The matrices $A$ and $B$ needn't be square. The reason why it's called equivalence, is that this definition satisfies the requirements of an [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation).

Now similarity is the special case where $A$ and $B$ are square and the invertible matrices are inverses of each other. So $A$ is similar to $B$ if there is an invertible matrix $P$ so that $P^{-1}AP=B$. And that is really all there is to it...neither $A$ nor $B$ need to be diagonal per se.

Now the significance of similarity becomes apparent when you interpret this in terms of linear algebra, where $A$ and $B$ are matrix representations of linear operators over some vector space, and the matrix $P$ is a change of basis matrix. If you have some matrix $A$ and you want to study how it affects certain vectors, it is a lot easier to do this if the matrix $A$ is diagonal...so if you can find a change of basis matrix so that the representation of $A$ relative to the new basis is diagonal that would be great...that is why we are especially interested in the case where $A$ is similar to $D$, a diagonal matrix. Of course this is not always possible, but then there are other (simple) canonical similarity forms we can try.